# Customize laravel sanctum unauthorize response

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, rest, laravel-sanctum

I am using laravel sanctum in my project, but I am facing a problem. I want to customize the 401 response code (unauthorized) to return a JSON when a token is invalid, something like this:

```
    {
    "data": {
        "code": 401,
        "book": null,
        "success": false,
        "error": {
            "message": "Not authenticated"
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of default response:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

How to achieve this in laravel sanctum? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Rendering exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions)

Add to `ExceptionHandler@register` *app/Exceptions/ExceptionHandler.php*

```
$this->renderable(function (\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $e, $request) {
    if ($request->is('api/*')) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Not authenticated'
        ], 401);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the Authenticate.php middleware to output the message you want OR catch the AuthorizationException to display the message you want in the Exception/Handler

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
        return response()->json([
         'message' => 'Not authenticated'
        ],401);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: Where to put render function?

Comment: i think he means there `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`

Comment: `\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException` not `AuthorizationException`