# laravel reponse json message not translated

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 8 with sanctum api (vue 3 spa).

I have never used localization before....and for this app I need that.

I created a middleware SetLocale with this content

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        app()->setLocale(config('app.locale'));
        if(session()->has('locale')) {
            app()->setLocale(session('locale'));
        }
 
        return $next($request);
    }
```

and registered in both web and api (app/Http/Kernel.php) @middlewareGroups

From the login form there is a select that change locale and make a post request to server to change the locale

```
Session()->put('locale', $request->input('locale'));
app()->setLocale(session('locale'));

return response()->json(['locale' => app()->currentLocale()]);
```

In the login form the server validation responds with the locale messages.... but the problem is the customized message ([Customize laravel sanctum unauthorize response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68516285/customize-laravel-sanctum-unauthorize-response)) it is not translated - it gives me in 'en' ... even if the locale is 'de'

```
$this->renderable(function (\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $e, $request) {
    if ($request->is('api/*')) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => trans('_custom.not_authenticated')
        ], 401);
    }
});
```

The file is there for every language _custom.php (resources/lang/de, resources/lang/en, etc )

example for _custom.php "de":

```
<?php

return [
   'not_authenticated' => 'Nicht berechtigt'
];
```

The message is still in en ... but if press login (without changing anything) .... the validation errors are in 'de'

Why ? What I missed ?

Could be that the message is returned before the middleware runs ?

*** **UPDATE 1** ***

It seems to work partially using in request Accept Language header .... but there is another problem.

In vue I have this approach for the axios:

```
const api = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    common: {
      'Accept-Language': document.documentElement.lang
    }
  }
});

export default api;
```

In the vue app when changing the language .... I also update the document.documentElement.lang value ... but when making a request it still the default value 'en'

Is there any way I can change dynamic the value for the 'Accept-Language' header instead of adding for each request the header ?

Comment: tried ..... the same thing

Comment: what is odd is if refresh the page in the page source `<html lang="de">` and the message is in english

Comment: add a `\Log::debug(config('app.locale'))` before `return response()` see what's printed in your logs?

Comment: in the log is 'en'

Comment: so, it seems like you didn't set your `app.locale` correctly, also when you refresh the page, the page doesn't show the correct language. I guess that the middleware didn't work correctly, because you store the locale info in `session`, but the middleware is `api`, the `api` is [stateless](https://restfulapi.net/statelessness/) which means it can't get the info in `session`. Try to solve this via adding a request header like `Accept-Language`, and in your middleware: `app()->setLocale($request->headers('Accept-Language'));`

Comment: setting the locale in 'ro' then refresh the page has 'ro' in html (documentElement.lang) .... so the locale works - it changes. In whatever language I change .... without refresh the page .... the validation errors are comming in the language that I selected.

Comment: since you are accessing the locale variable(en/de/ro) in `seesion` and you are using vue in client-render-mode, so when you refresh your page, the html (the translated message inside) is actually rendered by laravel which means it can access the `session`, but it would not work via `api` because of statelessness

Comment: and what do you mean by  - adding a request header like Accept-Language ? In the axios  when make request to change the locale ?

Comment: yes, add a request header like `Accept-Language`, you can do this in axios interceptor

Comment: But still not clear ..... why on the api response after changing the locale .... laravel know the currentLocale is that I set it ? `return response()->json(['locale' => app()->currentLocale()]);` So that means if set the locale 'de' then in response it confirms the default is 'de'