# How to properly return data with laravel sanctum?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to add authentication to my api using laravel sanctum. My test route is:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/test', function () { return 'API OK'; });
```

This return "API OK" when authenticated. That's ok, but also adds additional information in html format. I only need the response. What am I missing here?
This is a succesful case:
[image]

When token is invalid I'm rediredted to the login page. I just need the 401 error:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your problem with an invalid token this answer helped me to override the sanctum response [Customize laravel sanctum unauthorize response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68516285/customize-laravel-sanctum-unauthorize-response?rq=1)

The first part of your question when testing

`Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/test', function () { return 'API OK'; });`

I get API OK as the response, perhaps your config/sanctum.php or config/auth.php are misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

you need to catch the exception
to do it open **app/http/exception/Handler.php**
and add this code in the register method

```
        $this->renderable(function (\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $e, $request) {
        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        }
    });
```

I tied it and it worked for me